# Qt5 OS X menubar empty menu-item not hidden

Tags: macos, qt

I'm using Qt5 on OS X 10.8 and I'm creating an application with a menu bar in Qt Creator. Placing items like `Quit` or `Preferences` in the application menu works by specifying the `menuRole` accordingly. However, since those items need to be placed in some menu and then get moved automatically by Qt into the application menu I end up with empty menu items.

According to [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14610/#75437) the empty items should be hidden but for me they are not.

What I have is this:

```
File
    Preferences
    <Separator>
    Quit
Help
    About
```

`Preferences`, `Quit` and `About` are correctly moved to the application menu. Unfortunately `File` and `About` are still shown. How can I make Qt hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back to the project about 10 months and two minor Qt versions later, the problem is now gone. I just installed Qt 5.2 on OS X 10.9 and the app's menu is as expected.